# Java Swing method addActionListener error

Tags: java, swing

I am new to Java and trying to create a simple Swing program with two buttons, but I'm getting an error with `addActionListener`.

```
public class swingEx1  
{
   JFrame f;
   JPanel p;
   JLabel l;
   JButton b1,b2;

   public swingEx1()
   {
      f = new JFrame("Swing Example");
      p = new JPanel();
      l = new JLabel("Initial Label");
      b1 = new JButton("Clear");
      b2 = new JButton("Copy");
   }

   public void launchFrame()
   {
      p.add(b1,BorderLayout.SOUTH);
      p.add(b2,BorderLayout.EAST);
      p.add(l,BorderLayout.NORTH);
      p.setSize(200,300);
      f.getContentPane().add(p);
      b1.addActionListener(new ClearButton());
      b2.addActionListener(new CopyButton());
      f.pack();
      f.setVisible(true);
   }

   public static void main(String args[])
   {
      swingEx1 swObj1 = new swingEx1();
      swObj1.launchFrame();
   }
}

class ClearButton implements ActionListener
{
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e)
    {
        Button b1 = (Button) e.getSource();
        b1.setLabel("It it Clear Button");
    }
}

class CopyButton implements ActionListener
{
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e)
    {
        Button b2 = (Button) e.getSource();
        b2.setLabel("It it Copy Button");
    }
}
```

Line `b1.addActionListener(new ClearButton())` produces error:

> The method addActionListener(ActionListener) in the type
>   AbstractButton is not applicable for the arguments (ClearButton)

Line `b2.addActionListener(new CopyButton())` produces error:

> The method addActionListener(ActionListener) in the type
>   AbstractButton is not applicable for the arguments (CopyButton)

Comment: Compiles fine for me. 1) Class names should start with an upper case character. 2) do you have all the proper import statements. 3) The ActionListener code should reference a `JButton` not a "Button".

Comment: I'm not getting the error that you have described, however I do get `JButton` to `Button` cast error. Replace all `Button` references with `JButton`

Comment: I am using these two imports: `import javax.swing.*` and `import java.awt.*` and using Eclipse Version: Mars.2 Release (4.5.2).  Even after changing Button to JButton Eclipse is producing same error.

Answer (score 1):

In your two inner classes you should be using JButton and you are using Button.  This is probably why you are getting your exception.  I ran your code with the recommended changes and I got no error.

```
import java.awt.BorderLayout;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JLabel;
import javax.swing.JPanel;

public class swingEx1 {

    JFrame f;
    JPanel p;
    JLabel l;
    JButton b1, b2;

    public swingEx1() {
        f = new JFrame("Swing Example");
        p = new JPanel();
        l = new JLabel("Initial Label");
        b1 = new JButton("Clear");
        b2 = new JButton("Copy");
    }

    public void launchFrame() {
        p.add(b1, BorderLayout.SOUTH);
        p.add(b2, BorderLayout.EAST);
        p.add(l, BorderLayout.NORTH);
        p.setSize(200, 300);
        f.getContentPane().add(p);
        b1.addActionListener(new ClearButton());
        b2.addActionListener(new CopyButton());
        f.pack();
        f.setVisible(true);
    }

    public static void main(String args[]) {
        swingEx1 swObj1 = new swingEx1();
        swObj1.launchFrame();
    }
}

class ClearButton implements ActionListener {

    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
        JButton b1 = (JButton) e.getSource();
        b1.setLabel("It it Clear Button");
    }
}

class CopyButton implements ActionListener {

    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
        JButton b2 = (JButton) e.getSource();
        b2.setLabel("It it Copy Button");
    }
}
```

Comment: Even with the JButton changes I get the same error using Eclipse Version: Mars.2 Release (4.5.2)

Comment: I just ran it in eclipse fine, without getting an error.

Comment: What imports do you use?  Do you have it all in one file named SwingEx1.java?

Comment: I updated the code to show the everything including the imports

Answer (score 0):

I adjusted your ActionListener class (which is a separate defaulted-access class in your code) to an inner class and changed Button to JButton. It works.

```
 class ClearButton implements ActionListener
   {
       public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e)
       {
           JButton b1 = (JButton) e.getSource();
           b1.setLabel("It it Clear Button");
       }
   }
```

The GUI appears as follows:
1. Before clicking:
[Panel before clicking](https://i.stack.imgur.com/emnmC.png)
2.After clicking:
[panel after clicking](https://i.stack.imgur.com/71Y0J.png)

Comment: Imports includes: javax.swing.*; java.awt.*; java.awt.event.

Answer (score 0):

I changed my imports from:

```
import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.*;
```

to:

```
import java.awt.BorderLayout;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JLabel;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
```

This fixed the problem.  Not sure why the original imports didn't work.

Comment: You were missing `import java.awt.event.*;`